# Cannot execute SQL query on streaming replication setup master server Postgresql 9.5

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, database-administration, high-availability, postgresql-9.5

Error:

```
postgres=# insert into company values(4,'tom',21,'pune' ,21 );
^CCancel request sent
WARNING:  canceling wait for synchronous replication due to user request
DETAIL:  The transaction has already committed locally, but might not have been                                 replicated to the standby.
INSERT 0 1
```

Even after the error it is executing the query on the master as well as replicating transactions the slave.

On Master:

```
postgres=# SELECT pg_current_xlog_location();
pg_current_xlog_location
--------------------------
 0/1900D0C0
(1 row)
```

On Slave:

```
postgres=# SELECT pg_last_xlog_receive_location();
pg_last_xlog_receive_location
-------------------------------
 0/1900D0C0
(1 row)
```

synchronous_standby_name set on master from config file(set by me) is different from the application_name I see it on record of pg_stats_replication table. Many of the solutions have suggested to change the application name. However, I am not sure from where it is taking application name as walreceiver on the master.

On Master:

```
postgres=# select application_name, sync_state from pg_stat_replication;
 application_name | sync_state
------------------+------------
 walreceiver      | async
(1 row)

postgres=# show synchronous_standby_names;
 synchronous_standby_names
---------------------------
 slave1
(1 row)

postgres=# show synchronous_commit;
 synchronous_commit
--------------------
 on
(1 row)
```

One of the solution I found is to create tablespace dir under path '/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/' which I currently dont have. I am not sure if that solution will work for 9.5 Postgresql.

Any help on this is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Changing *synchronous_standby_names* to 'walreceiver' resolved the error. Followed link [To know more about synchronous_standby_names](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-replication.html)